# Saving styles for a blog

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am creating a blog and I am wondering how to allow an admin user to add styles to their post. For instance, if they would like to bold a few words in a paragraph or add an image in the middle of the paragraph.

I am using MVC 4 and entity framework. The plan is to have a text area for the user to create a post and save to the database. And also allow the user to do basic formatting to the text.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to make a simple textarea that can save your text in your database then after that you can change that textarea and use some plug-ins like  **ckeditor** (*references: http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor, http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor*), you may also like to use **nicEdit** which I'm also using right now (*http://nicedit.com/*), or you may want to use **WYSIWYM Markdown Editor[wmd]** (*https://github.com/derobins/wmd, http://code.google.com/p/wmd/*) like this one on stack overflow.. And another one **Rich Text Editor [RTE]** (*demo is here: http://www.kevinroth.com/rte/demo.htm*, main site is here: http://www.kevinroth.com/rte/)

Answer (score 2):

You will want to implement a (possibly jQuery?) HTML WYSIWYG editor, such as [Redactor](http://imperavi.com/redactor/)
.  There are many WYSIWYG plugins out there that are configurable and hook to your textarea.